# how to add products to my wishlist from my view?

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to make a wish list in my project,when i press a button in each product it should add this product to the list and get the user_id and the product_id from there tables but that's not happening can u help me , and this is the controller

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use DB;

class listController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getIndex(){

        $list=DB::table('wishlist')->get();
        $product=DB::table('products')->
        get(['name','id','salary','image_name']);
        $user=DB::table('users')->get(['id']);
        return view('contents.wishlist')->with('list',$list)
                                        ->with('product',$product)
                                        ->with('user',$user);
    }
    public function postCreate(Request $request){
        $id=$request->input('id');
        $user_id=User::get(['id']);
        $product_id=$request->input('product_id');

        DB::table('wishlist')->
        insert(['id'=>$id,'id'=>$user_id,'product_id'=>$product_id]);
        return redirect('/wishlist');
    }
}
```

and this is the form i'm using :

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

<div class="wrapper-breadcrums">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-24">
                <div class="breadcrumbs">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="home"> <a href="http://localhost/shopsite/public/home" title="Go to Home Page"><span >Home</span></a> <span class="separator">/ </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="cms_page"> <strong>My Account</strong>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.wrapper-breadcrums -->

<div class="em-wrapper-main">
    <div class="container container-main">
        <div class="em-inner-main">
            <div class="em-wrapper-area02"></div>
            <div class="em-main-container em-col2-left-layout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-18 col-sm-push-6 em-col-main">
                        <div class="em-wrapper-area03"></div>
                        <div class="my-account">
                            <div class="my-wishlist">
                                <div class="page-title title-buttons">
                                    <h1>My Wishlist</h1>
                                </div>
                                <form id="wishlist-view-form" action="wishlist/create" method="post">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="inYgLvzSpOOWWVoP" />
                                        <table class="data-table" id="wishlist-table">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                    <th>Product Details and Comment</th>
                                                    <th>Add to Cart</th>
                                                    <th></th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                @foreach($product as $p)
                                                @foreach($list as $l)
                                                @foreach($user as $u)
                                                @if($l->user_id == $u->id)
                                                <tr id="item_6">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <a class="product-image" href="product_detail" title=" {{$p->name}} "> <img src="{{asset('images/')}}/{{$p->image_name}}" width="113" height="113" alt=" {{$p->name}} " /> </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>

                                                        <h3 class="product-name"><a href="product_detail" title=" {{$p->name}} "> {{$p->name}} </a></h3>

                                                        <div class="description std">
                                                            <div class="inner">The must-have tee for his third birthday!</div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <textarea name="description[6]" rows="3" cols="5" title="Comment" placeholder="Please, enter your comments..."></textarea>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="cart-cell">

                                                            <div class="price-box" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"> <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-258"> <span class="price"  content="{{$p->salary}}">${{$p->salary}}</span> </span>
                                                            </div>

                                                            <div class="add-to-cart-alt">
                                                                <input type="text" class="input-text qty validate-not-negative-number" name="qty[6]" value="1" />
                                                                <button type="button" title="Add to Cart" onclick="addWItemToCart(6);" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <p><a class="link-edit" href="#">Edit</a>
                                                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td><a href="#" title="Remove Item" class="btn-remove btn-remove2">Remove item</a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                                @endforeach
                                                @endforeach
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                        <div class="buttons-set buttons-set2">
                                            <button type="submit" name="save_and_share" title="Share Wishlist" class="button btn-share"><span><span>Share Wishlist</span></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="button" title="Add All to Cart" class="button btn-add"><span><span>Add All to Cart</span></span>
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="submit" name="do" title="Update Wishlist" class="button btn-update"><span><span>Update Wishlist</span></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons-set">
                                <p class="back-link"><a href="home"><small>&laquo; </small>Back</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- /.em-col-main -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-18 em-col-left em-sidebar">
                        <div class="em-wrapper-area02"></div>
                        <div class="em-line-01 block block-account">
                            <div class="block-title em-block-title"> <strong><span>My Account</span></strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="block-content">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Account Dashboard</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#it/">Account Information</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Address Book</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">My Orders</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Billing Agreements</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Recurring Profiles</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">My Product Reviews</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">My Tags</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="current"><strong>My Wishlist</strong>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">My Applications</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Newsletter Subscriptions</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="last"><a href="#">My Downloadable Products</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.em-line-01 -->

                    </div><!-- /.em-sidebar -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.em-wrapper-main -->


@stop
```

Comment: what you are getting in result?

Comment: it just moves me to the wishlist view but without any add :

Comment: and here's the button code : <li><a href="wishlist" type="submit" class="link-wishlist" name="submit" title="Add to Wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a>
                                                    </li>

Comment: when i tried to write the button like that : <li><a href="{{action('listController@postCreate')}}" type="submit" class="link-wishlist" title="Add to Wishlist" type="submit">Add to Wishlist</a></li> 
it gives me that error : Controller method not found. @DinanathThakur

Comment: Have you tried removing the redirect statement from the `postCreate` method and dumping the result of the insert instead: `dump(DB::table('wishlist')->insert([...]));`. It might return `false` if you say no entry is saved, in which case you might want to see if the values you pass are valid. Also I don't know your structure for the `wishlist` table, but usually the `id` column is used as a primary key with auto incrementing values, so passing it via the request and then inserting it manually doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: i use the primary key because in the wishlist form i'll show them so i use it , the problem that it doesn't get information about the product (product_id) or the (user_id) and doesn't store anything !!!!! @Bogdan

Comment: If the data is not passed via the request, you need to post the code that sends the request (I'm guessing it's a form).

Comment: and that's how i summon the function in each button : <li><a href="{{action('listController@postCreate',array('id',$p->id))}}" type="submit" class="link-wishlist" name="submit" title="Add to Wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a>
                                                    </li>

Comment: Your form action should be `action={{ action('listController@postCreate') }}`. And don't use anchor as submit button. Use a `<input type="submit">`

Comment: the button don't work like that it should be link so can it be done with that ?? @smartrahat

Comment: Anchor tag usually send data as `get` not as `post`. First of all change your form action. Then try with submit button.

Comment: there is something u should know , the anchors are in another views not the wishlist view @smartrahat

Comment: Ohh... I'm sorry. I can see you have to submit button. So, you are submitting your form by any of these button?

Comment: i want the button to insert the data u see above , but the button is as a link href and in another views , then i want the button to insert the data into the database when pressed